# Proving Compactness of a Set of Vectors

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

Take an infinity norm defined as $\|f\|_\infty=\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$. This is basically an $L_\infty$ norm. Also let $q_n$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and $c_i,i=0,\ldots,n$ be its $n+1$ coefficients.

Also define a function $E(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n)=\|f-q_n\|_\infty$. If $S=\{\textbf{c}=(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n)\in\mathbb{R^{n+1}}:E(\textbf{c})\le\|f\|_\infty+1\}$. How to show that this set $S$ is compact?

My idea is to show that this set is closed and bounded since that will imply compactness.

Comment: Yes. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ showing that the set is closed and bounded is probably the easiest approach. (Assuming it is true, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, letting $\phi_c(x) = \sum_k c_k x^k$, you are asking if
$S=\{ c | \|f-\phi_c\|_\infty \le 1+ \|f\|_\infty\}$ is compact.

Since $S$ is finite dimensional, we just need to show that $S$ is closed and bounded.

Note that $\|c\|_* = \|\phi_c\|_\infty$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and since the space is finite dimensional, all norms are equivalent, in particular, $\|\cdot\|_*$ is continuous.

If $c \in S$ then $\|c\|_* = \|\phi_c\|_\infty \le 1+2 \|f\|_\infty$. Hence $S$ is bounded.

Since $c \mapsto \|f-\phi_c\|_\infty$ is continuous, $S$ is closed.

Comment: how does the $2$ come multiplied with $\|f\|_\infty$?

Comment: From the triangle inequality: $\|\phi_c\|_\infty-\|f\|_\infty \le \|f-\phi_c\|_\infty \le 1 + \|f\|_\infty$.

Comment: In the last line, how does continuity of a function imply closedness of the set? Is there a theorem like that?

Comment: The inverse image of a closed set by a  continuous function is closed.

Comment: How is $\|c\|_*=\|\phi_c\|_\infty$?

Comment: It is the definition of the $\|\cdot \|_*$ norm?

Comment: Don't you need a lower bound on $\|c\|_*$ as well?

Comment: Why would I need a lower bound. In a normed space a set is bounded **iff** the norm of elements of the set are bounded.